object fit: fill is not stretching the image and I want to stretch it
My question is not similar to this question because in this question op wants to fill the image, clipping it if necessary, however for me, I want to stretch the image, not clipping it but matching the exact dimensions of the container.
I have following simple code-


img {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

.narrow {
    width: 100px;
    height: 150px;
}

.fill {
   object-fit: fill;
}
<h2>object-fit: fill</h2>
<img class="fill" src="https://placehold.co/800x1000" alt="Wide Image" />
<img class="fill narrow" src="https://placehold.co/800x1000" alt="Narrow Image" />



My Image is not stretching to fill the length and width of the img element. Why is my image not stretching in both directions but maintaining its aspect ratio, and how to make it stretch? thank you!
Edit- to clarify, I want the image to be stretched, not the image to be be clipped to fit. So object-fill: cover will not help-
For Reference

cover
The replaced content is sized to maintain its aspect ratio while
filling the element's entire content box. If the object's aspect ratio
does not match the aspect ratio of its box, then the object will be
clipped to fit.
fill
The replaced content is sized to fill the element's content box.
The entire object will completely fill the box. If the object's aspect
ratio does not match the aspect ratio of its box, then the object will
be stretched to fit.


the images  you used aren't good: https://jsfiddle.net/onchq582/ (the code works fine)

@Temani Afif oh okay, so it also depeneds on the kind of image somwhow? thanks!

also note that fill is the default value no need to specify it
